# How to remove dropdown from wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, navigation, walker, dropdown

I dont want to have dropdown (select - options) in my wordpress menu, even in mobile or lower width devices. I know I can use css to hide it, but I want to remove it at all. I googled for an hour and I found that I should use a custom walker on Roots!!!! but I dont know whats that and how. please help me, I am a newby.

Comment: Which Theme do you use?

Comment: meadowhill - http://wordpress.org/themes/meadowhill

Comment: In the `js/functions.js` exists a function `initMainNavigation`. This function creates the dropdown button.

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding your situation. May you please elaborate? Add pictures to give a better visual reference on where you are.

Answer (score 2):

We can use depth parameter of [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) to set how many levels  menu walker traverses.

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_id'=>'nav', 'theme_location'=>'header-menu' , 'depth' => 1) );
```

You can create a child theme so that updates won't override during updates.

Create child theme and copy code from `header.php` of parent theme then replace the code

```
 wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu_id'=>'nav', 'theme_location'=>'header-menu' ) );
```

with the above code.

More Info:
[child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#How_to_Create_a_Child_Theme)

Answer (score 1):

Since WP `v3.3.0` you can use filter [`wp_nav_menu_args`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_nav_menu_args) to alter arguments of function [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) that used to display a navigation menu. Add this code in `functions.php` of your theme files. You can change functions name `wpse155177_nav_menu_args`.

```
/**
* @see wp_nav_menu()
*
* @return array $args Array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
*/
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'wpse155177_nav_menu_args', 1, 1 );
function wpse155177_nav_menu_args( $args )
{
    //lookup theme_location ie: header-menu
    if ( isset( $args['theme_location'] ) && 'header-menu' == $args['theme_location'] ) {
        $args['depth'] = 1; //levels of the hierarchy are to be included
    }

    return $args;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to move in menu settings "menu voices"(pages as :home, who we are, what to do, etc) alling them one under another.